# Private Communication between client and server using websockets play 2.3.x

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

I am newbie to scala and can't figure out sending private message to client using websocket.

Here is my controller:

```
object Client extends Controller {
  def socket(uuid: String) = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request =>
    out => ClientWebSocket.props(uuid)
  }
 // Test Method to send message to websocket connected client
  def sendMessage(guid: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    val system = ActorSystem("default")
    val out = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ClientWebSocket], guid))
    out ! SendUpdate("Message Recieved")
    Ok
  }
}
```

Here is my actor class:

```
object ClientWebSocket {
  def props(uuid: String) = Props(new ClientWebSocket(uuid))
  case class SendUpdate(msg:String)

}

class ClientWebSocket(uuid: String) extends Actor {
  import ClientWebSocket._

  def receive = {
    case SendUpdate(msg:String) =>
      sender ! "Message is " + msg
  }
}
```

When I call sendMessage with uuid of client, I am getting akka dead letters encountered error.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, in your WebSocket method, you need to use the provided `ActorRef` instead of `sender`. `sender` is probably something else in the hierarchy.

```
class ClientWebSocket(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import ClientWebSocket._

  def receive = {
    case SendUpdate(msg: String) =>
      out ! s"Message is $msg"
  }
}
```

Second, you are receiving dead letters in `sendMessage` because you are replying to your controller, which unfortunately is not an Actor.

The problem is that you cannot get hold of the `ActorRef` and since you don't know the name of the actor, you cannot use an `ActorSelection`. So you would need to make a WebSocket call to your own app, call it from web browser / JavaScript or do some hacking with the action to get to the actor.

**Edit**

Your `ClientWebSocket` could register (e.g. in `preStart` via `ActorSelection` or via an `ActorRef` as props parameter) with another actor that keeps a `Map[String, ActorRef]` reference to all websockets and in turn monitors them using death watch. That actor would then forward your `SendUpdate` to the correct websocket actor. Since you can only return Props in `acceptWithActor`, you are not able to form a real hierarchy.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I haven't been able to figure out "hack" to get the actorref for websocket connection. Any thoughts on how to do that? Only thought I have right now is to register `ClientWebSocket` actorref with a SupervisorActor using uuid as the key and then using uuid to get actorref in my controller methods. I am not sure if this is the best approach or not?

Comment: Yes sure, I've updated my answer. Although I'm not quite sure why you need WebSockets if you only want to send messages between actors.

Comment: The system I am working on needs websockets to send/receive message to/from connected clients. The message that server needs to send to client can be generated by a 3rd system and put on queue to be processed by this scala/play app. The approach I am taking is to have websocket connection opened by client and my play app keeps track of the connection/client using uuid and when a message comes on queue with client uuid, play app gets hold off actorref which has websocket connection to client and sends the message to client. Am I missing something here with my approach?

Answer (score 1):

The out parameter is an ActorRef, you will use it to send messages to the Client, therefore you need to keep it in your Actor.

```
object Client extends Controller {
  def socket(uuid: String) = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request =>
    // out is an actor to what the outbound messages should go to respond to remote client
    out => ClientWebSocket.props(uuid, out)
  }
}
```

Your ClientWebSocket actor is as follows:

```
class ClientWebSocket(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) extends Actor ...
```

And the companion object is as follows

```
object ClientWebSocket {
  def props(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) = Props(classOf[ClientWebSocket], uuid, out)
}
```

In the ClientWenSocket you can Register/Deregister the Actor with a CentralWebSocketControl Actor as:

```
class ClientWebSocket(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    CentralWebSocketControl.instance ! RegisterMe(uuid)
  }

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    CentralWebSocketControl.instance ! UnregisterMe(uuid)
    super.postStop()
  }
}
```

The CentralWebSocketControl Actor can be as:

```
class CentralWebSocketControl extends Actor {

  val clientActors = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, ActorRef]()

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case RegisterMe(uuid) =>
      clientActors += uuid -> sender()
    case UnregisterMe(uuid) =>
      clientActors -= uuid    
  }
}

object CentralWebSocketControl {
  val instance = Akka.system.actorOf(Props(classOf[CentralWebSocketControl]), name = "CentralWebSocketControl")
}
```

To send a message to a given ClientWebSocket identified by an uuid, you can send a message to CentralWebSocketControl that may delegate the message to the registered ClientWebSocket.

```
class CentralWebSocketControl extends Actor {

  val clientActors = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, ActorRef]()

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    ...    
    case SendUpdateTo(uuid: String, msg: String) =>
      clientActors.get(uuid) match {
        case Some(actor) =>
          actor ! SendUpdate(msg)
        case None =>
          ???
      }
  }
}
```

and finally

```
class ClientWebSocket(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case SendUpdate(msg) =>
      out ! msg
  }
  ...    
}
```